# Extracting links in a sequence from a table in a webpage using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to extract links of pdfs from this [page](https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/sanghi-industries-ltd/sanghiind/526521/corp-announcements/) using Selenium in python

I managed to extract the entire table that contains the rows and the links to the pdfs.

```
driver.get(company_link)
announcement_link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="heading1"]/h1/a').get_attribute('href')
driver.get(announcement_link)
table = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="lblann"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td')
```

I am looking for a shortest possible method to create a list of all pdf links in a sequence.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to extract links of pdfs from this page using Selenium in python

In the page you provided, each link has a unique class `tablebluelink` which makes it easy to select all of their hrefs with a XPath expression selects the `href` attribute of all `a` elements that have a `class` attribute with the value `tablebluelink`:

```
//a[@class='tablebluelink']/@href
```

and then use `find_elements_by_xpath` in order to iterate over them:

```py
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='tablebluelink']/@href")
```